# Rewriting FileAdmin class

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I want to forbid create/edit dirs, and edit filenames. How i supposed to do it?

```
class myFileAdmin(FileAdmin):
    def can_upload(self):
        return False
    def can_delete(self):
        return False

    def can_mkdir(self):
        return False
    def can_delete_dirs(self):
        return False

    def can_rename(self):
        return False
```

I tried to rewrite `FileAdmin` class like above, but it didn't affect anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, to rewrite this class, you dont need to define this rules as functions, just set it like variables.

```
class myFileAdmin(FileAdmin):
    can_upload =  False
    can_delete =  False
    can_mkdir =  False
    can_delete_dirs =  False
    can_rename =  False
```